# How to connect to a specific website on localhost?

Tags: apache

I have a local Apache server running on the network and I've got a number of tester machines. I want to be able to connect to a specific website on the localhost, at the moment it just connects to the first website.

For example: 192.168.1.125/mywebsite.

I've looked around I cannot find the method of conneciton, I know it's something really simple but everywhere I look answers a different problem. (Maybe this is too simple).

So basically I'm asking, how do I access the other servername though the browser. (setup is like so:)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot c:/vhosts/website1
  ServerName website1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot c:/vhosts/website2
  ServerName website2
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried 
192.168.1.125~mywebsite
192.168.1.125:80/mywebsite.
192.168.1.125-mywebsite.

Can anyone help me here? Also what's the English for this? Namespace? Name-server or something?

*I get the error "Object not found" with these.

Comment: Basically, when trying to access a different URL, you simply add the path to the file you want to go to. Like: www.example.com/subfolder/hello.html. What you're trying to do however sounds like you're trying to access a subfolder. Meaning, you need an index.html or .php in that subfolder, which will be used as 'default filename'.

Comment: No I'm not trying to access the different sub-folder, trying to access another website. For example on the main PC I simply put /mysite1 or /mysite2 and it works. From another Pc though 192.168.1.125 can only access mysite1 and not mysite2. Sort of like a nameserver.

Comment: @OllyDixon - What is the platform?

Comment: Windows, running latest Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name-based serving of apache is based on the actual hostname in the request.  To make this work, you have to be able to reference that IP by any names you need.  You have to be able to do `http://hostname/` and not `http://IP` for name-based virtual hosts to work.

You can do this either with a hosts file (for a single host) or over DNS.  Neither is a programming problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Use virtual hosts. i.e. have something like this in the `httpd.conf` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName <make up a hostname here e.g. example.com>
  DocumentRoot "<path to the web site files>"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "<path to the web site files>">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then add the following to the to the hosts file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
127.0.0.1 <made up hostname as above>
```

Then you can access the web site as `http://<hostname as above>`

Guess it will be the same for Linux except the file would be `/etc/hosts`. You can repeat this as often as necessary.

**EDIT** Use the following it `/etc/hosts` on both the machine running the server and the machine running the browser

```
192.168.1.125 website2.example.com
192.168.1.125 website1.example.com
```

Then edit the two copies of the virtual hosts stuff above using the `website1.example.com` and `website2.example.com`

Comment: Thing is I can only connect using IP, how do you change the name using IP?

Comment: 192.168.1.125 website2 , not working. VirtalHost works on host machine though. Can only access website1 still. Sure you can use space?

Comment: Doesn't work, you can't put a space as the servername. My problem is I've just realized that I'm hitting the first virualhost only.

Comment: @OllyDixon - It is not a service name. It is a mapping between hostname and an IP address. See http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts or

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark

Map your testing machines to your server

> ```
> ~/test_machines/web_1
> ~/test_machines/web_2
> ~/test_machines/web_3
> ```

Then add the site entries to your vhost.conf.  Use VirtualDocumentRoot from mod_vhost_alias.  You can see the examples here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

Comment: I'm trying to access the websites from the test machines, seems I can see the main website which is on localhost root but anything else I cannot see only on the test machines.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you.
host_machine = http://main_host/test_machine
You're trying to access host_machine from other test machines(so you can view the other test machines from the one calling host_machine)?

Comment: Correct, It's a case of servername? (which are setup). How does one change the servername from an IP? (http://IP/nameofsite). I've tried: http://~192.168.1.125/web2

Comment: Please review the edit to my answer dealing with VirtualDocumentRoot